# create android static library using makefile

Tags: android, c, makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to build android static library to use PJsip. I have a simple file NTjsua_good.c with 3 functions that handles some pjsip functionality. I'm using [this manual](https://tariqzubairy.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/arm-binaries-static-library-for-android/) to create libs. But now I'm stuck on make-file. This is what it looks like:

```
ANDROID_NDK_BIN:=/cygdrive/с/other/android-toolchain/bin
CC := $(ANDROID_NDK_BIN)/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
CPP := $(ANDROID_NDK_BIN)/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
AR := $(ANDROID_NDK_BIN)/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
CFLAGS:= -I/cygdrive/c/other/StaticLibraryTest/src 

#STATIC_LIB_SRC:= NTjsua_good.c
.c.o:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< \
STATIC_LIB_SRC = NTjsua_good.c\
STATIC_LIB_OBJ= NTjsua_good.o\
OUT = ccStaticLib.a\
$(OUT): $(STATIC_LIB_OBJ) \
$(AR) -crs $(OUT) $(STATIC_LIB_OBJ)
```

But after executing it like this: `make -f make-static-library.mak` I get ar error: `no rule to make target «/cygdrive/с/other/android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar», needed by «/cygdrive/с/other/android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc».  Stop`
I can't figure out what is wrong with my makefile

Comment: Are the tool binaries (gcc/g++/ar) present on your system?

Comment: yes. I extracted android NDK so they are in с/other/android-toolchain/bin

Comment: For a simple library as yours, it's much easier to build an `Android.mk` file.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken but Android.mk file is needed when building Java app using Eclipse. But my approach is to use Xamarin

Comment: You don't want the `\ ` at the end of the lines. The manual put them there when listing multiple .c/.o objects. `\ ` at the end of the line tells make to ignore the newline, and process everything as a single line.

Comment: @mtijanic if I remove all backslahes (\\) at the end of all lines I get an error `make-static-library.mak:9: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: One other thing - in make,  `[tab]` vs `[space]` matters, as tabs are very specific. So, you need to insert a tab before these two lines: `[tab]$(CC) ($CFLAGS) .....` and `[tab]$(AR) -crs ....`. Also add an empty line after both of those, for good measure (not strictly needed, but can help avoid some problems)

Comment: @mtijanic I added [tabs] as you said. But now I get another error `make: /cygdrive/с/other/android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found`. But gcc tool is in that directory. here is a screenshot http://snag.gy/mugcV.jpg

Comment: I've had problems with cygwin and make before that could be related. Unfortunately, you can't write `c:\other...` into make directly, as `:` is interpreted as a special character. But, you can try this.. Remove the first line of the makefile, and before calling make do `set ANDROID_NDK_BIN=c:\other\android-toolchain\bin`, then call `make -f  blahblah.mk`

Comment: @mtijanic I removed ANDROID_NDK_BIN from makefile and did this `export ANDROID_NDK_BIN=/cygdrive/c/other/android-toolchain/bin` in console. And gcc started it's job. But now I have linking problem NTjsua_good.c:3:29: fatal error: pjsua-lib/pjsua.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h> ). Though I add link-flag in makefile

Comment: You need to do the same thing for your `c:\other\StaticLibraryTest\src`, - it is trying to include it from a nonexistent place. So, just export ANDROID_SRC path, and add that to CFLAGS, like `CFLAGS := -I$(ANDROID_SRC)`

Comment: @mtijanic I did as you said. But still getting the same error ( like there is no such file in a directory ). But I wrote all my path variables in unix-style `/cygdrive/c/other/StaticLibraryTest/src/` but still gcc can't find header files

Comment: Finally I installed Ubuntu and compiled code there with no errors. Thank you all)